# Using Dream Factory with Android Studio

Tags: android, import, libraries

I'm trying to use DreamFactory from [GitHub](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/android-sdk) with Android Studio, but my attempts haven't been successful so far.

How can I import this library and use it for connecting to `dream.factory.cloud` ?

The guide is for Eclipse, and not for Android Studio. Also, the sample app does not use Gradle. I don't know how to fix this, and I would need some pointers.

Comment: This site is for actual coding problems, If you ask people to write you a tutorial you might not succeed.

Comment: @Urahara I believe this is a completely legitimate question, as the guide on how to use is for Eclipse, while the project has to be imported into your project as a module for Android Studio. That, and it seems to me that the SDK uses Maven to build itself, while the "sample" app despite being updated a month ago, still uses Eclipse, and does not use Gradle for dependencies. Outdated mess. *Anyways, this question is regarding the usage of Android  Studio for this specific usecase*.

Comment: Write and answer then. I marked it as 'Should Be Improved`

Comment: @МаксимСухинин try to clone the git repository, then import it as a module in a project you started for Android. Then, if it adds the Sample App, then delete sample app from the project modules. Then, go to Project Structure, Dependencies, then add the DreamFactory project as a compile time dependency. I hope it works, even though DreamFactory uses Maven for this android project instead of Gradle (GET WITH THE TIMES, PEOPLE)

Comment: GitHub files (project) contains three parts conditionally: 1) sample app, 2) .jar libraries 3) source .java files. I can import only sample app as a module, it's don't intrested me. I do following steps: 1) create empty module 2) copy source .java files structure to it 3) copy .jar libraries to my app and created module libs folders. The result is error: 
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Problem solved. I'm execute my steps above, and delete dublicate libraries. Thank you all, sorry for such a rude question, my English and my poor skills.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is uploaded here by me, just followed the instruction here after you have download my project here`https://github.com/segunmicheal27/dreamfsctorysample-androidstudiosample/tree/master`
you don't need any modification all you need is the study the code and modified it to what you want